# How can I get all the Facebook pages liked by a user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to know if Open Graph even allows to get all the pages liked by someone (and, if possible, only in a certain category), and if so, how would I be able to do that ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/likes to see how this can be achieved.

Basically you need to request `/me/likes` with an Access Token with `user_likes` permission.